# jQuery .html() is not working in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In ajax call jquery `.html()` is not working!

When i use `.alert()` function it's working, but in `.html()` function as i said it s not working!  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            var ad = $('#ad').val();
            var soyad = $('#soyad').val();

            $.post('program.php','ad='+ad+'&soyad='+soyad, function(cevap){
                $('#sonuc').html(cevap);                
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

**this is php code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ad'])){
        echo 'Adınız: '.$_POST['ad']."\n";
    };

    if(isset($_POST['soyad'])){
        echo 'Soyadınız: '.$_POST['soyad']."\n";
    };
?>
```

[this is full html of issue](http://chscelikcati.com/ask/fullhtml.JPG)

[please download all file over this link](http://chscelikcati.com/ask/program.rar)

Comment: this looks fine, hit `F12` on chrome and open `console` to view the error, and post it here.

Comment: What `console.log(cevap);` outputs?

Comment: are you sure element with id `sonuc` exists and its `unique`?

Comment: I would recommend passing an object as your second parameter to $.post: `$.post('program.php', { ad: ad, soyad: soyad }, function (cevap) { ... });`. Let jQuery handle the potential encoding of parameters for you.

Comment: what do you mean of `working` & `not working`? please provide more details

Comment: thanks your advice mehdi, am very new! please write something abouth issue.

Comment: D4V1D, console.log(cevap); outputs is same,
Learner, #sonuc is unique,

Answer (score 0):

Use the XHR preventDefault() function on the button's click event. Obviously, you'll have to put it before you make the .post call. Something like:

$('button').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //rest of the stuff

Should do the trick.